# JSpinner without negative values

Tags: java, swing, netbeans6.8, jspinner

I'm building a small application in netbeans,I use a JSpinner component to set the quantity of a product.How can I set the spinner to take only positive values?Is there a choice inside Netbeans that I can set or a method for the `JSpinner`?

**EXTRA:**

`spinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 20, 1));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for [JSpinner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) you have to implements [SpinnerNumberModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerModel.html)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SpinnerModelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new SpinnerModelTest().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeUI() {
        SpinnerModel modeltau = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.0002, 0.0001, 100.0000, 0.0001);
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(modeltau);
        ((JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getFormat().setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(spinner);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to set the Minimum ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#setMinimum(java.lang.Comparable)

Comment: This is a link to a really old version of Java.

Comment: @jzd - yeah, I had been wondering about those many old references as well. Until I noticed that they come up very high (I remember even as first, cannot reproduce it right now - searching for 'JSpinner' 1.4.2 is second in the list) in a google search.

Comment: Yes some of the older API's are high on Google's results but I think that is just because there are so many links on the web pages that goolge crawls that point to the old APIs.

Answer (score 1):

It works with [r0ast3d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8069923/3764804)'s library reference:

```
((SpinnerNumberModel) mySpinner.getModel()).setMinimum(0);
```