# How to limit JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, jspinner

The valid range for this application is 0 to 9 but there seems to be no NetBeans 7.0.1 JSpinner minimum or maximum value setting. Is there another way to limit the range of this JSpinner to 0..9?

Comment: See [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) which allows to specify min/max values in the constructor

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In my Netbeans 7.3 i followed theese steps:

Step 1:

[image: swing spinner spinnernumbermodel]

Step 2:

[image: swing spinner spinnernumbermodel]

Step 3:

[image: swing spinner spinnernumbermodel]

And final step 4:

[image]

That works for me.

Answer (score 22):

```
// from 0 to 9, in 1.0 steps start value 5  
SpinnerNumberModel model1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(5.0, 0.0, 9.0, 1.0);  
JSpinner spin1 = new JSpinner(model1);
```

Answer (score 15):

You'll have to use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#SpinnerNumberModel%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) constructor of `SpinnerNumberModel`.

Snippet:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Limiting value for a JSpinner");
  SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 9, 1); //default value,lower bound,upper bound,increment by
  JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);
```

Answer (score 2):

> The valid range for this application is 0 to 9 but there seems to be
>   no NetBeans 7.0.1 JSpinner minimum or maximum value setting. Is there
>   another way to limit the range of this JSpinner to 0..9?

- yes but without bothering insert code and/or with generated code from GUI Palette
- add [SpinnerListModel (easiest for this requirement and example in Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#model)) or [wrote own SpinnerNumberModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8069904/714968)