# How to assign a SpinnerModel to a JSpinner using IntelliJ IDEA Swing Editor

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jspinner

Using IntelliJ IDEA GUI Editor, I want to achieve something like this:

```
final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
spinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(25, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1));
```

Still, the list of properties doesn't show anything even closely resembling what I'm looking for, the only `JSpinner` bean property exposed being `editor`:

[image]

The only work around I've figured out is using a custom creation code.

I understand *Swing* has gone out of fashion for quite some time already, but I can't believe UI designer of the leading Java IDE is so inferior feature-wise compared to [*Eclipse WindowBuilder*](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) or [*NetBeans Matisse*](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html).

Comment: UI designer was never a priority for IntelliJ IDEA, it's more focused on the code editing and inspections. You may consider JFormDesigner plug-in if you do a lot of Swing.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks, already figured that out. To be more precise, built-in GUI editor in IDEA is merely a joke. JFormDesigner is good indeed, but free alternatives (WindowBuilder/Matisse) are more than enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in IntelliJ, go to the Spring form designer and select the JSpinner and tick the box called Custom Create. Then you can use code such as below:

```
private void createUIComponents()
{
    SpinnerNumberModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(10, 1, 99999, 1);
    myJSpinner = new JSpinner(sm);
}
```

in the Form.form file. Here is my code which I adapted for my purposes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880988/17892492)